# How to add onlick event on tag a in php?

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
$link = '<a href="http://test.com/t123#readmore" class="">Read more</a>';
```

And my code php add onlick event

```
$link = preg_replace( '#<a(.+?)href="(.+?)"(.+?)(</a>)#s', '<a href="$2" onclick="test();"></a>', $link);
```

But error can't add onclick on tag a, how to fix it ?

```
<a href="http://test.com/t123#readmore" onclick="test();" class="">Read more</a>
```

Comment: Real solution: Use JavaScript to attach the handlers you want.

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty good to me... you're missing `Read More` though... add your third match into your `preg_replace` statement:

```
$link = preg_replace( '#<a(.+?)href="(.+?)"(.+?)(</a>)#s', '<a href="$2" onclick="test();">$3</a>', $link);
// <a href="http://test.com/t123#readmore" onclick="test();"> class="">Read more</a>
```

Demo: https://eval.in/66235

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using a regex to do this. If you're going to do this, do it with Javascript and jQuery instead

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#testa').click(function() { test(); });
});
</script>
<a href="http://test.com/t123#readmore" onclick="test();" class="" id="testa">Read more</a>
```